# Получить путь для папки ProgramFiles

Tags: c#

```
string ProgramFiles = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
```

этот код на 64 битной винде  выдает путь до "C:\Program Files (x86)", а как получить путь до папки ProgramFiles?

Comment: _On a non-x86 system, passing ProgramFiles to the GetFolderPath method returns the path for non-x86 programs._ - судя по этому описанию, код запускается не на 64х битной Windows

Comment: В документации написано, что на 64-битной системе он должен "Program Files" возвращать. В настройках проекта всё в порядке?

Comment: да, убрал галочку предпочтительно 32 все заработало спс.